# Quantifiers: "most flowers bought at airports" vs. "most of the flowers bought at airports"

Tags: determiners, quantifiers

I came across this exercise in one of the Oxford books.

- ***Most** / **Most of the** flowers bought at airports are safe, about 90%.*

Shouldn't we use "most of the" when we are talking about a specific set of something?

Comment: I may be very naive, but what danger do the other 10% of the flowers bought at the airport pose?

Comment: In the Answer Key, it's "Most flowers bought at airports are safe, about 90%."

Comment: @MooPer That's because the word _the_ is missing from the other option. So _most flowers_ is correct, _most of flowers_ is incorrect, and _most of the flowers_ would also be correct, but wasn't one of the choices.

Comment: That comma sure is weird though.

Comment: Please show the actual book, linking if possible. I'm sure no editors would allow 'Most of flowers bought at airports are safe, about 90%', especially in a grammar. Unless you had to point out an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use ***most flowers*** or ***most of the flowers***. **Most of flowers* is incorrect.

This [Grammar site](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/article4d.html) explains that

> When speaking in general, we use ***most*** to refer to *a quantity of an **unspecific** group of people or things*. ***Most*** is *a determiner (a quantifier)* to the subject noun:
>
> - ***Most*** students ask questions.

As for ***most of the***, it says:

> When speaking ***specifically***, we use ***most*** *with a **prepositional phrase*** that *limits the number to a specific group*:
>
> - ***Most of the** students* [PP] ask questions.

Here, *most* is accompanied by the PP *of the students* to refer to *an understood (known) group of students*.

So depending on whether you want to speak unspecifically or specifically, use either *most flowers* or *most of the flowers*.

Comment: No. The flowers in OP _are_ specified by the postnominal defining participial phrase 'bought at airports'. The alternatives are in this case totally synonymous (ignoring possible pragmatic concerns such as 'punchier'). // With your examples, with no post-specification, the comments given apply.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm looking at the edited question and racking my brains trying to figure out why "Most flowers" is incorrect, it's your edit, Edwin. You included the definite article, when there was none in the original.

Comment: "Most of flowers" is very ungrammatical.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A
 As you say, '_Most of_ flowers ...' is totally unacceptable, and shouldn't be suggested on ELU. I edited it out, so that the alternatives are '_Most_ / _Most of the_ flowers bought at airports ...', ie '_Most_ flowers bought at airports ...' / '_Most of the_ flowers bought at airports ...'

Answer (score 0):

This has pretty much been answered already. In this case, since "Most of" is missing *the*, it would be "Most." If *the* were present, then either would make equal sense.

Answer (score -1):

"Most / Most of" sounds like someone trying to sound "scientific", or authoritative, or otherwise highbrow.

Perhaps a student, or a beginning journalist.